# Can't get chrome context menu to show for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I've gone through the other posts about this, and I still can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my implementation of the chrome contentMenu api. I've just copied the code from a Chrome API tutorial, and I don't get any errors, but it's just not showing up in the menu when I right click.

Am I missing something?

***manifest***

```
 {
      "manifest_version": 2,      

  "name": "Chrome extension practice",
  "description": "Practice",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": 
  [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", "script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "contextMenus",
    "background",
    "https://twitter.com/",
    "http://twitter.com/"  
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {       
   "default_title": "Practice",
    "default_icon": "fa-moon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

***background.js***

```
 window.onload = function() {
    //CONTEXT MENU this should go somewhere else, but we'll need to resolve onload conflict
    alert("Background script loaded");
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: "custom-context-a",
        title: "Hide Tweet",
        contexts: ["launcher", "all"],
    }, function(){
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    });

    chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(contextClicked.bind(this));
};

function contextClicked(e){
    console.log(e.menuItemId);
}
```

EDIT ---

still not sure what's wrong with my code, but ExpertSystem's example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915554/chrome-extension-context-menu-how-to-append-div-to-page-after-clicking-menu-ite) post works

Comment: Is the alert firing?

Comment: @levi yes - it fires as soon as I reload the extension, but not when I reload a new window (I think that's normal though right?)

Comment: When you say "I don't get any errors", have you checked the JavaScript console of the background page? (You can open it by clicking on the corresponding *background page* link in *chrome://extensions/*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `chrome.contextMenus.create` out side of `window.onload`. And `alert` doesn't work in background.js