# How to make a Chrome Extension Sticky?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension which is an extension for a chat room. I need it to be sticked on the screen like this [sticky note chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sticky-notes/nbjdhgkkhefpifbifjiflpaajchdkhpg)

Here's how it looks:
[click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfZVQ.png)

I am using the following code in the popup.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chat Adda</title>
    <style>
    body{}
    .resize{min-width:640px; min-height:480px; resize:both; overflow: auto;}
    .row{background-color:#5cbf2a;text-align:center;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="resize">
    <iframe id="theFrame" src="http://chatadda.com" style="width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <div class="row">
    <span><a href="http://chatadda.com" target="_blank"><img src="/open.png" width="32px" height="32px"/></a></span>
    <span><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chatadda.android&hl=en" target="_blank"><img src="/android.png" width="32px" height="32px"/></a></span>
    <span><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A//chatadda.com/" target="_blank"><img src="/facebook.png" width="32px" height="32px"/></a></span>
    <span><a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=ChatAdda.com%20-%20Chat,%20flirt,%20date%20and%20make%20new%20friends.%20Chat%20with%20strangers%20in%20private%20chat%20rooms.%20It's%20fast,%20secure%20and%20free." target="_blank"><img src="/twitter.png" width="32px" height="32px"/></a></span>
    <span><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A//chatadda.com/" target="_blank"><img src="/google.png" width="32px" height="32px"/></a></span>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I do it?

Comment: `position: absolute` in CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that what you show as an example is a Chrome App, not an extension. **You cannot replicate that (that is, the [`chrome.app.window` API)](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window) in an extension.** And Chrome Apps are already actively deprecated: you can't publish new ones (except for ChromeOS).

If you just need a separate window, you can call `chrome.windows.create` with the `"popup"` type. But you won't be able to keep it on top of other windows. You don't specify what you need exactly, maybe that's not required.

Solution [suggested by Edmund Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40364648/934239) (using content scripts to inject your UI into the DOM) would add your UI *inside* other pages. Might be useful, but it's a broad and complex topic how to make it work properly.

Comment: An extension *can*, effectively, actively keep a popup window on top of other windows (i.e. have it, effectively, be modal). However, not while interacting with the other windows.

Comment: Yes, you can constantly focus a window. It's unlikely to be what's needed.

Comment: @Makyen can you post how to do it? I think that's what he is asking for.

Comment: @Macraze This is essentially a Very Bad Idea. You won't be able to interact with the rest of Chrome (or even the system).

Comment: @Xan Makyen says he can effectively do it.

Comment: @Macraze Yes, effectively do what I just described. Imagine an application stealing focus if you try to click away from it. That's what it'll be like. It's a *bad idea*. You can re-focus a window with `chrome.windows.update` (on a loop, or by focus change events), if you need the technical details.

Comment: @Macraze, As Xan stated, it is possible to do it by forcing focus to your window whenever the focus leaves your window. Yes, I can post code, as I have already written and tested it (both Chrome and Firefox). However, as Xan has stated, it is, generally, a bad idea, *unless* the goal is to have a [modal window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) for interaction with the user. I wrote it to compensate for Firefox WebExtensions (continued)

Comment: (continued) not having modal user interactions from background scripts (e.g. `alert()`)). This methodology is not viable if your goal is to have the window float on top of other windows for interaction *in addition to* the webpage. It is my belief that what the @MaroofMandal desires is to have a panel which can be interacted with while interacting with the webpage in the tab. That does not work with what I have mentioned. Thus, I have not posted code here. My initial comment was, perhaps, just picking a nit in Xan's answer which appears to have caused some confusion.

Comment: @Makyen We have what appears to be a [help vampire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) on our hands. The question has a form of "I want X to be like Y, [code dump], do it for me" without even specifying the exact requirements. I recommend not posting the code unless (at least!) requirements are clarified.

Comment: @Makyen Please post the code. Atleast I want to stick my chrome extension however bad the idea may be. Without sticking it my extension is meaningless as it is chatting platform, it needs to be stickable.

Comment: @Makyen, re "*does not work*". I think it will work because even if you position it at the top layer, the user can still click the parts of the webpage that isn't covered by it.

Comment: @Pacerier What I was describing was opening an entire new browser window with something that was intended to be "sticky". It doesn't work, generically, to have the user also be able to interact with another window, because when the other window takes the focus, that window is brought to the top of the OS' window stack, which will make the one you're wanting to be "sticky" be underneath the newly focused window and not visible for any areas where those browser windows overlap. You could create a *content script* which has a "sticky" interaction, but that's *in the page/tab*, not the window.

Answer (score 1):

`popup.html` is only the popup after you click the chrome extension icon. What you need is adding a `content.js` file. Check out this SO thread for details.

[Chrome Extension Context Menu: how to append div to page after clicking menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915554/chrome-extension-context-menu-how-to-append-div-to-page-after-clicking-menu-ite)

[How to insert HTML with a chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103183/how-to-insert-html-with-a-chrome-extension)

Google Documentation:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

The rest is just appending a dom node to the page, and use CSS to position it.

Comment: Please elaborate how do I do that. Also here's the link to my Chrome extention - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chat-adda/hbgpnkckjaojeleclpnmceencbemlkce
 please check it to understand my needs.

Comment: too broad to ask that. see the docs and show what you tried and whats not working.